# Parametric equation with a trigonometric function in exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, exponential-function, parametric

I'm having trouble thinking of any solution or idea to solve this math problem. Any help will be appreciated.

$(a^2 - 1)*2^{-\sin^2 x} = a^2 - 4a + 3 $,

$a = ?$

The equation should have real solutions.

Comment: Do you mean $(a^2-1)*2^{-\sin^2 x}=a^2-4^a+3a$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you show us what have you tried we’ll help you.

Comment: Mathjax:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: have you studied factoring:  $$a^2-4a+3=(a-3)(a-1)$$.  Can you factor $(a^2-1)$

Comment: What is $x$ in the exponent?

Comment: **Hint:** $a^2-1 = (a+1)(a-1)$

Comment: Put all variables of the same kind to one side of the equation

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct equation? You can't get a numerical value for $a$ from that equation. The best you can do is to give an expression for $a$ in terms of $x$, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a=1$ $$(a^2 - 1).2^{-\sin^2 x} = a^2 - 4a + 3$$ is simply $$0=0$$ which is trivial so $x$ could be any real number. Otherwise we divide both sides by $(a-1)$ to get    $$(a+ 1).2^{-\sin^2 x} = a- 3$$ For $a=-1$ the equation turns into $$0=-4$$which has no solution. Otherwise we get  $2^{-\sin^2 x}=(a-3)/(a+1).$ Note that  $1/2\le 2^{-\sin^2 x}\le 1$. $ 1/2\le (a-3)/(a+1)\le 1$ has solutions on $a\in [7,\infty)$. Thus  we have solutions if $a=1$ or  $ a\in  [7,\infty) $.

Comment: Check my edited solution.

Comment: to me it seems that $a \ge 7$

Comment: I fixed my error. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2):

For $a=1$ the equation is satisfied for every $x$. Let's look for solutions different from $1$, so we can divide both sides by $a-1$, getting
$$
(a+1)2^{-{\sin^2x}}=a-3
$$
so
$$
2^{-{\sin^2x}}=\frac{a-3}{a+1} \tag{*}
$$
(note that $a=-1$ would lead to a contradiction).

Since $-1\le-{\sin^2x}\le0$, we have $1/2\le 2^{-{\sin^2x}} \le 1$.

Thus we need
$$
\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{a-3}{a+1}\le 1
$$
that is satisfied for $a\ge7$. Conversely, the equation (*) has solutions for every $a\ge7$.

How to find $a\ge7$? We need
$$
\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{a+1-4}{a+1}\le 1
$$
that is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\le 1-\frac{4}{a+1}\le 1
$$
that is
$$
0\le\frac{4}{a+1}\le\frac{1}{2}
$$
Therefore $a+1>0$ and $8\le a+1$, that is, $a\ge7$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a\in \lbrace [1,1] ,  [7, \infty) \rbrace \subset \mathbb {R}$$

if you graph it, with desmos (by setting $a=y$) for instance, indeed $a=1$ all $x$.  But with the equation so presented you can arrive at other ordered pairs $(x,a)$ such that $a \neq 1$.  Can someone account for this dilemma?

Allowing that $a \neq 1$ and solving it for $a$ in terms of $x$ produces

$$a(x)=3+\frac{4}{2^{{\sin^2 x}}-1} \ge 7 \quad \forall x$$
and for example 
$$a\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)=7 \implies \left(\frac{n\pi}{2},7\right) \quad  \bigg {|} \quad n \in \mathbb {Z}$$

Comment: Please check my solution

Comment: I have fixed the solution and $a\ge 7$  is correct.

Comment: @Mohammad I see that you did.   Down check removed.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comments.